# Choreo integration WSO2 - Analytics

Tags: wso2

We trying to integrate our own project in WS02, to bring informations with Choreo
I followed the documentation (generate the key for authentication, but I'm not getting information from Choreo analytics,

Follow prints of what was done.

Config authentiction token:

[image]

Insights (doesn't working)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the printscreen you sent it looks like there are some issues in the .toml file, first you should uncomment the "#" in front of [apim.analytics], if you don't do this, the configuration will not be processed correctly. There are also two letters on the same line that shouldn't be there "hy", you may remove that.

Do this, restart the WSO2 APIM nodes and send some requets to APIs served by the gateway, then check if the analytics data appears on Choreo.

Also, please notice that Choreo Analytics is an enterprise feature that is only available through an active WSO2 subscription. Without the subscription, the API key you generated will only last for 2 weeks before becoming unactive. If you wish to talk about getting a WSO2 Support Subscription for you company you can reach out to WSO2 through the link below:

https://wso2.com/contact/